# How to use liferay dynamic data list in another dynamic data list form template

Tags: list, dynamic, liferay

I have 2 dynamic data lists (jobs and persons) in liferay 6.2.3
I want to use 'jobs' list as a select control in persons form template(when you add a new person you will select a job from select).

Is this possible? I can't figure it out, if so, how can I do this?
Form template for dynamic data list is a XML.